# Docker child processes do not inherit niceness of daemon

Tags: docker, nice, cgroup

I often run a lot of `docker` containers, which sometimes cause my system to freeze momentarily. To prevent this, I made a service that automatically sets the `niceness` of `docker-containerd` a bit higher. I thought that this would  cause all new child processes to inherit this `niceness`, but when I start a new container all processes have a `niceness` of `0`

Here is a screenshot of htop:
[image: htop screenshot: top docker-containerd has niceness ("NI") 10. But all child process have NI 0.]

I'm not sure if this is caused by how `Docker` works internally or something else (`cgroups` perhaps?).

Does anybody have an idea how I could automatically give all containers-processes a higher `niceness`? I don´t want to use the `docker`-specific features like `--cpu-period`, since that means I'll have to specify these arguments each time that I create a new container.

Answer (score 0):

its the other way round for me. All my containers inherit the nice level from dockerd. But I want only dockerd to run in higher priority.

Comment: This is how I would expect it to work, since child processes inherit the niceness of their parent when they get spawned. I made this post over a year ago and I don't remember the specifics. You could try to change the niceness of the daemon after the containers are started. This post does a quite decent job of explaining niceness: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37901/273800

Comment: dockerd uses containerd to launch the containers. When i set the `Nice` for `containerd.service`, all the containers got the same `Nice`.